# Alt + F keys always switches to virtual terminal on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, ubuntu-gnome, virtual-console

As of recently something has changed the behavior of Alt on my system. I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.2 LTS. When I press for example <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, the system opens the 4-th virtual terminal and only when I come back to GUI (with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>) the window actually closes. The same holds for pressing left and right arrows with <kbd>Alt</kbd> pressed. I would like to restore the default behavior so that I would need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F*</kbd> to get to virtual terminals.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior - very annoying. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: @joh, actually it has vanished since then. I have done an update, but I did not explicitly try to solve this issue. I have no idea what caused this in the first place unfortunately.

Comment: after rebooting the problem has vanished for me as well. Hope it stays that way :)